# django anchor url with sharrre plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I'm using the sharrre plugin with the blog on my Django site, and in the script I reference a link to the share buttons as  The functionality works fine, as the script handles the popup share windows as desired, but it ends up taking me back to my homepage, rather than refreshing the current page.

It seems as if this is because django turns the  into, for example, localhost:8000# rather than localhost:8000/current-page# as would be the desired result.

So I guess my question is how do I get my script to reference localhost:8000/current-page# ?  Or is there something else I should be considering?

For reference, this is the script:

```
$('#shareme').sharrre({
    share: {
        googlePlus: true,
        facebook: true,
        twitter: true
    },
    template: '<ul class="share-buttons"><li><a href="#" class="facebook share-button"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li><li><a href="#" class="twitter share-button"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li><li><a href="#" class="googleplus share-button"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></li></ul><div class="share-count">{total} | Shares</div>',
    enableTracking: true,
    enableHover: false,
    render: function(api, options){
        $(api.element).on('click', '.twitter', function() {
            api.openPopup('twitter');
        });
        $(api.element).on('click', '.facebook', function() {
            api.openPopup('facebook');
        });
        $(api.element).on('click', '.googleplus', function() {
            api.openPopup('googlePlus');
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: What I've done, which gives me the intended result, is replace the "a" tags with "button" tags and remove the "href" since I really don't need that page refresh. I suppose adding a "return false" somewhere to the jquery may have also been an option.  That said, I'm still somewhat curious about the <a href="#"> functionality in django, but it feels like I must be completely overlooking something.